# Eclipse Formatter: How to avoid indentation of method declaration after annotation?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter, method-declaration

I have a method declaration with an annotation that is formatted by Eclipse Mars as follows:

```
@Override
        void addLoadShiftingConstraints() throws NoSuchDataException {
    //method body
}
```

I would like to not indent the method declaration:

```
@Override
void addLoadShiftingConstraints() throws NoSuchDataException {
    //method body
}
```

Currently I have following formatter setting for the method declaration:

[image]
Right click on Project =>Properties=>Java Code Style=>Formatter
=>Edit active profile => LineWrapping => Method Declaration => Declaration => **Wrap where necessary**

If I would choose the option **Do not wrap** instead, the unwanted indent would vanish. However, I would like to keep the wrapping for long declarations.

Is this an Eclipse bug or is there an additional setting for the Annotations that I would have to change in order to avoid the indent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed [a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471791) ([related](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=479613)). The workaround is to set the setting to "Do not wrap" as you describe or to add an access modifier like `private`.

Answer (score 1):

(Can't comment due to insufficient reputation, but found this answer through search and it applies to a second situation.)

I faced a similar problem with indentation of local variables, which only took affect when a comment was placed after an annotation. @Stefan's answer worked for this also.

```
 @SuppressWarnings("JavaReflectionMemberAccess") // implicit method Enum#valueOf(String)
 Method method = class_.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
```

was being reformatted to

```
@SuppressWarnings("JavaReflectionMemberAccess") // implicit method Enum#valueOf(String)
        Method method = class_.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
```

but was fixed with the addition of a `final` modifier:

```
@SuppressWarnings("JavaReflectionMemberAccess") // implicit method Enum#valueOf(String)
final Method method = class_.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
```